# Pivot csv data?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, pivot

I'm new to Python so please forgive if this is easy. I have a csv file that contains data as follows:

```
Symbol,date,price
apple, 23/12/2016, 50
apple, 26/12/2016, 51
apple, 27/12/2016, 52
google,23/12/2016, 70
google,26/12/2016, 71
google,27/12/2016, 72
```

I need to write a new csv file that looks as follows:

```
Date, apple, google
23/12/2016,50,70
26/12/2016,51,71
27/12/2016,52,72
```

The code I have so far is as follows. However, I can't seem to get the symbols across as columns.

```
import csv
import os

csv.register_dialect(
    'mydialect',
    delimiter =',',
    )

symbol, date=[],[]

with open('EB_CUT2.csv',"rt") as dfile:
    thedata = csv.reader(dfile, dialect ='mydialect')
    for row in thedata:
        if row[4] not in date:
            date.append(row[4])
        if row[0] not in symbol:
            symbol.append(row[0])
dfile.close()

ebout = open('EB_CUT.csv',"wt",newline='')
wr = csv.writer(ebout)
for val in date:
    wr.writerow([val])
ebout.close()
```

Comment: Please format your csv file so we can help you better

Comment: Pandas is great for this sort of thing.

Comment: This isn't transposing. Transposing means swapping rows and columns, so that if you had a `NxM` matrix, you get `MxN`. In your example some of the columns are gone.

Comment: your output doesn't make sense.

Comment: Thanks, yeah looks like Pandas is the way to go will check it out.

Comment: The term is pivot, not transpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Non-pandas solution:

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime
import os

MY_DIALECT = 'mydialect'
csv.register_dialect(MY_DIALECT, delimiter =',', skipinitialspace=True,)

daily_prices = {}
with open('EB_CUT2.csv', "rt", newline='') as dfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(dfile, dialect=MY_DIALECT)
    for row in reader:
        date = datetime.date(datetime.strptime(row['date'], '%d/%m/%Y'))
        entry = daily_prices.setdefault(date, {})
        entry[row['Symbol']] = row['price']

all_symbols = sorted(
    set(symbol for value in daily_prices.values() for symbol in value))

with open('EB_CUT.csv', "wt", newline='') as ebout:
    writer = csv.writer(ebout)
    writer.writerow(['Date'] + all_symbols) # header
    for date, prices in sorted(daily_prices.items()):
        row = [date.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')]
        for symbol in all_symbols:
            row.append(prices.get(symbol, ''))
        writer.writerow(row)
```

If you wanted to initialize the `daily_prices` dictionary from any existing `'EB_CUT.csv'` file—effectively the inverse of the last step shown above—which it sounds like you may from your comment below about wanting to merge in more csv files later, the following code would do that:

```
daily_prices = {}
if os.path.isfile('EB_CUT.csv'):  # existing file?
    # Initialize daily_prices from existing csv file.
    with open('EB_CUT.csv', "rt", newline='') as inf:
        reader = csv.reader(inf)
        next(reader)  # skip header row
        for row in reader:
            date = datetime.date(datetime.strptime(row[0], '%d/%m/%Y'))
            days_prices = daily_prices.setdefault(date, {})
            for symbol, price in row[1:]:
                days_prices[symbol] = price
```

An alternative to reading the current csv file to initialize it would be to always also save the `daily_prices` data that corresponds to current csv file in a separate file in whatever format you choose. It could be written and read back in very easily by using the `pickle` or `json` modules.

Comment: Thanks very much for the help, works great. I now just need to add it in so that for any new dates or symbols it appends the output file as I will have multiple csv's in the first step but Ill see if I can work that out. The Pandas solution for me didnt work as I got a lot of Pandas errors maybe it is not installed properly on my PC. thanks again

Comment: You're welcome. To append data to the output file, first initialize the `daily_prices` dictionary from what is currently in the file (instead of it starting out as an empty dictionary as shown in my answer), then add data to that from one or more csv files, then finally rewrite the entire output file.

Answer (score 0):

A pandas solution:

```
import pandas 

df = pd.read_csv('EB_CUT2.csv', index_col=1, parse_dates=True)
df2 = pd.pivot_table(df, values='price', columns=['Symbol'], index=df.index)
df2.to_csv('EB_CUT.csv')
```

Content of `EB_CUT.csv`:

```
date,apple,google
2016-12-23,50,70
2016-12-26,51,71
2016-12-27,52,72
```